# Jquery fade page transition

Tags: jquery, html, transition, fadein, fadeout

I'm posting a question here in order to have some help. I'm trying to put a Jquery fadeout/fadein page transition on my one page horizontal website. For that, I use the following script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".panel").fadeIn(1000);

    $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $(".panel").fadeOut(500); 
        $(".panel").fadeIn(1000);
    });    
});
```

I built a fiddle with this script and it works. Then, I added this script on my computer local page, and there, all the animation effects on my one page slider don't work, I just have the fadeout/fadein which work. If I remove this script, all animation effects rework. So,I copy and past the whole code of my local page on a new fiddle ([**click here to see**](http://jsfiddle.net/jarod51/uzqR4/)). and on this fiddle all working.
I'm a little bit stuck because I don't understand why it works on the fiddle and not on my local computer page. On the console, I don't have any errors.
Do you have any advice or idea how to solve my problem? I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I declared on my local webpage in the following ways : <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: You're using a different version of jquery-ui and jquery in the fiddle. I'd start there.

Comment: The fiddle still seems to work with jquery 1.10.1 and 1.11.0, so it might not be the version. Where are your scripts included? in the Head? at the bottom of the body?

Comment: Hi caspian, thanks for your replies, I included the script in the head not at the bottom of the body. PS: I also tried scripts included at the bottom of the body and I have same result.

Comment: I copied the code to an html file and javascript file. It worked for me locally using jquery-1.8.3 and jquery-ui-1.10.4.js
I noticed you have a custom.js on your jquery-ui, did you customize this file?

Comment: my custom.js looks like the same as in the fiddle link. I just copy and past my custom.js on in the js fiddle. What do you mean by customize this file ?

Comment: I would try copying the code from your fiddle to some local files and see if that fixes it? It might be just an issue with the local file you have? non-ascii characters or something weird.

Comment: ok thanx caspian, keep me posted. This issue drives me crazy.

Comment: Caspian, I tried at my end to re-copy and re-past my fiddle on local files, it doesn't work. Did you reproduce the same issue ?

Comment: No - everything worked fine locally.

Comment: That's weird caspian, I actually tried my code in chrome it doesn't work and with firefox it works. Which browser did you use ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was using chrome and it worked fine... I wonder if it is an issue with chrome caching the js file. Try clearing your browser cache or ctrl-f5 on the page.

Comment: Ok thx Caspian, I will try to clear my chrome browser cache. This situation is really weird. It works for you and not for me :(. I really apprecite all the time that you past to help. Thx so much again.

Answer (score 0):

include

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

in your head tag.

Even without these, you can work in google chrome I hope.

even u can save those *.js file in your local system and link it

Comment: Hi Vivek MVK, I tried your solution neither work. I'm totally lost.

Comment: I also to save the js file on my computer, same effect. Nothing works :(

Comment: add anyone of these and tried?? dnt add both. Tried in chrome?

Comment: Yes Vivek, I tried in chrome. No errors in the console and always the same thing. Animation effects don't show.

Comment: I really appreciate your help Vivek. I hope I could resolve this problem :'(

Comment: ya surely you can. if you use servers like xampp this problem will be solved

Comment: which is weird, if I recopy and repast the code from fiddle on a local files it doesn't work.